# MySQL fulltext does not search for short emails

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I have a fulltext index on a number of columns and i'm trying to do a MATCH AGAINST IN BOOLEAN MODE on those columns, trying to find an email address. Here are the results:

- if i search for "test@email.com" (with quotes) - the query returns correct results
- if i search for "a@b.com" (with quotes) - the query does not return anything

Can someone tell me why a short email a@b.com does not get returned and how would i solve this?

Here's the query i'm using:

```
SELECT MATCH(email, phone, title, description) AGAINST('"a@b.com"' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS score 
FROM thetable WHERE MATCH(email, phone, title, description) 
AGAINST('"a@b.com"' IN BOOLEAN MODE) ORDER BY `status` DESC, score DESC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a combination of two problems:

1. `@` isn't considered being a 'word character', and neither is `-`, so searching for `a@b.com` actually comes down to searching for words `a`, `b` and `com`
2. `a` and `b` are shorter than ft_min_word_len

The solution would be to make `@` and `.` being considered word characters. There are several methods listed on http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html

The most practical one would be adding a custom collation as described in

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/full-text-adding-collation.html

Answer (score 0):

Update:

a)You need to set    **ft_min_word_len = 1** in my.cnf.

b) Output of show variables

```
ft_min_word_len                                   | 1
```

c) Fired below query:

```
mysql> SELECT name,email FROM jos_users WHERE MATCH (email) AGAINST ('a@b.com') limit 1;
 +--------+---------+
 | name   | email   |
 +--------+---------+
 | kap | a@b.com |
 +--------+---------+
 1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Hope this will help.

~K

---

I think you need to change **ft_min_word_len**

As specified in [MySQLdoc fine tuning](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html)

> The minimum and maximum lengths of words to be indexed are defined by
> the ft_min_word_len  and ft_max_word_len system variables. (See
> Section 5.1.4, “Server System Variables”.) The default minimum value
> is four characters; the default maximum is version dependent. If you
> change either value, you must rebuild your FULLTEXT indexes. For
> example, if you want three-character words to be searchable, you can
> set the ft_min_word_len variable by putting the following lines in an
> option file:
>
> [mysqld]
> **ft_min_word_len=3**
> Then restart the server and rebuild your FULLTEXT indexes. Note particularly the remarks regarding myisamchk in the instructions
> following this list.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I suspected as much. And indeed my min length is set to 3. And if i search for "abc@b.com" - it works. But then what i don't understand is: a) abc@b.com is 9 chars long and is searched in quotes as a phrase, so why does this setting have any effect at all? b) if indeed min word length has effect - then the word "b" is only one character, how come that works?

Comment: It does work, thank you. I just have trouble understanding what mysql considers a "word".

Comment: @Marius: can you please consider marking Hartmut's answer instead of this one, as it is the better answer. For the benefit of others coming here to learn, Hartmuts answer describes both issues; the MIN_WORD and the fact the @ symbol is being ignored because it's reserved for the @ distance operator.